# Передача данных в Angular2 через Inputs

Tags: angularjs, angular2

Не могу передать данные в angular2 между файлами.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsPostsComponent } from './news/post.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-app',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  directives: [NewsPostsComponent] 
})

export class AppComponent { 
  title: string;
  posts: string[][];

  constructor (){
    this.title = 'Journal';
    this.posts = [
      ['Finish News!', '', '03:49 09.10.2016'],
      ['Start News', '', '02:49 09.10.2016'],
      ['Hello World', '', '01:49 09.10.2016']
    ];
  }
 }
```

post.component.ts

```
import { Input, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
    selector: 'news-post',
    templateUrl: './app/news/post.component.html'
})


export class NewsPostsComponent {
    @Input() posts: string[];
}
```

app.component.html

```
<news-post [posts]="posts"></news-post>
```

Вот ошибка, помогите, уже всё перерыл. Версия ангуляра самая свежая.
[image: Вот ошибка]

Comment: что за версия ангуляра? directives вроде как уже устарели и удалены

Comment: в AppComponent: `posts: string[][];` в директиве `posts: string[];` найди разницу

Comment: @Grundy самая новая, та что на сайте https://angular.io/. А как исправить?

Comment: ага. похоже несколько ошибок

Comment: @Grundy http://imgur.com/a/F7RJ4 , не помогло

Comment: чего не помогло-то? :-) на картинке не видно ошибок

Comment: @Grundy вот http://imgur.com/a/WV8su

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46548/discussion-between-roman-kravets-and-grundy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

свойство `directives` у Component было удалено в [версии rc.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc6-2016-08-31)

Вместо него теперь нужно добавить твои компоненты в раздел `declarations` в твоем `NgModule`